# How to update the argument of a destination when going back to it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement some sort of account profile where the current user can do some modification to their profile. I already added the profile syncing on the server side, but I'm currently stuck at how do I update the local copy of the account. The calling `Fragment` of the account profile `Fragment` is already receiving an account argument so I thought if I could find a way to pass back the updated account, then I'll be golden. With this in mind, I thought maybe I need to listen to back presses and use `navigate()` to go back to the calling `Fragment` and passing the updated account to it. But `NavController` doesn't seem to support it, at least I can't find any function that looks like it lets you listen/override to the back presses on the documentation. I found that you can use this:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner){
    
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work for me. Now I'm getting an error for some reason when the code below was already working previously.

```
val action = DashboardFragmentDirections.showAccountDetailsFromDashboard(currentAccount)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

The error looks like this:

> androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to
> instantiate fragment
> com.app.name.fragments.management.AccountProfileFragment: could not
> find Fragment constructor

I already did a couple of invalidate cache and the error still occurs.

What I currently want to do is fix this weird error and find a way to update the received account of the calling `Fragment`. The process of doing so doesn't matter

Comment: Navigation arguments are immutable, so anything that changes over time shouldn't be arguments in the first place. Usually there'd be a User repository you make that your fragment would get the current user from.

Comment: I forgot to add because it's not that related to NavController, but I do have the account details in a `SharedPreference`. But if I go that route, I need to do more stuff than finding a way to pass back the account, I think.  I didn't think of using a repository because I didn't need to handle multiple accounts. Thanks for the info though. I'd consider that

Comment: A repository is more of a design pattern as part of your [data layer](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/data-layer#architecture), it doesn't imply any particular kind of storage so if you have the information in SharedPreferences, that's perfectly valid.

Comment: But is there no way to do what I wanted to do? I think it's a perfectly valid use-case. With how you can chain `Fragments`, it looks like you can pass around an  argument if you wanted to

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if it's the right way to do things, but this is how I implemented what I wanted to do.

My solution is heavily based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61948678/10464730). So here's my code

This needs to be in the `MainActivity`

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Then on the `Fragment` that you want to listen the back presses, you add this inside atleast `onViewCreated`:

```
/**
 * this is the listener for the toolbar back press
 */
val callback: OnBackPressedCallback =
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            val action = AccountProfileFragmentDirections.goBackToDashboardFromAccountProfile(updatedAccount)
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }

ctx.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)

/**
 * this is the listener for the actual back press
 */
val callback2 = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    val action = AccountProfileFragmentDirections.goBackToDashboardFromAccountProfile(updatedAccount)
    findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```